# Passing a USB2.0 connection through a GX12 Connector

Tags: usb, connector, impedance, cables

In the system that I am designing, I need to connect and power a system that is placed 2 meters away from the processor. I am unable to find a good USB connector that is IP67 rated and not bulky in size. GX12 connector seems the optimal size for the system connection. I wanted to know if I can pass USB signals through the GX12 connector along with a shielded custom cable with very low impedance.
If I am unable to use the GX12 Connector, what measures should I consider while making a custom USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cable itself has the right impedance (90 ohms nominal diff, 45 ohms single ended), the connector transition should have only minor influence on signal integrity at USB2 speed.

Get a sample cable and try a TDR test on it to check.

That said, here’s a USB connector range that is IP67 rated: https://www.mouser.com/new/switchcraft/conxall_mini-usb_typeB/

Comment: I also wonder whether DeHeisenberg is getting characteristic impedance confused with actual impedance. We expect any wire to have a low resistance, low inductance, low capacitance (so low impedance); 90 or 45 ohms is the characteristic impedance which is (loosely speaking) basically the *ratio* of the inductance and capacitance

Comment: I think you mean *resistance*. That’s not going to be much of a problem at 2m with #24ga cable.